# NHibernate vs petapoco loading mechanism

Tags: nhibernate, petapoco

I am having the difficulty to understand NHibernate an petapoco loading mechanism.  Actually I did a test to compare how both behave upon a query.

My class is as follows:

`UserTest.cs` with the following properties:

```
private string name;
private int id;
private int customerId;

public int ID
{
    get { return id; }
    set { id = value; }
}

public string Name
{
    get { return name; }
    set { name = value; }
}

public int? CustomerID
{
    get { return customerId; }
    set
    {
        if (value != customerId)
        {
            customerId = value;
            if (this.ID > 0)
            {
                DoSomeOtherWork();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When I do a `User.Load` in NHibernate, I have observed that `DoSomeOtherWork` is never called whereas in PetaPoco, when I do a query from loading `User` such as `Connection.db.Fetch<UserTest>(...)` or `Connection.db.Query<UserTest>(...)`, I can see that `DoSomeOtherWork` is called.

Why is that so?

Is there a way to avoid calling `DoSomeOherWork` when using PetaPoco such that it has the same behaviour as NHibernate? I don`t want to use`PetaPoco.Ignore`as I need to get and set the`CustomerID`.

Comment: I only know NHibernate, but NHibernate only goes to the DB if you use session.Get<>() whereas session.Load<>() creates a proxy with the Id set and fetches the entity later when a property/method is accessed. Notice that .Get can return null - .Load assumes the entity exists and is never null, but will throw if the entity does not exist when a property is accessed.

Comment: From @Goblin explanation, I would like to ask petaPOCO experts, is there any such possiblility in petaPOCO, of what has been explained for the session.Get<>() whereas session.Load<>(). Do we have the possibility of having to have methods doing same work as get and Load separately?Because in the case I have explained above it is clear that the entities are being accessed upon a query

Comment: **Very important**: Your code implies property value setting ordering. In case of your code results would be different when you'd first set `ID & CustomerID` compared to setting first `CustomerID & ID`. This is very bad because your class has *hidden agenda* and has to be used correctly in correct order.

Comment: I worked on a project that had several god objects which depended on incredibly complex orders for the setters when being loaded from the database and then an entirely different set of behaviors for serialization. I bet you can imagine the awful effects of this. It is my stern advice that the properties used for persistence and serialization be as simple and normalized as possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PetaPoco it a micro-ORM (much lighter than Nhibernate) and materializes your POCO object when you fetch the record. There is no other magic than that, so the answer is:

### No, you can't avoid calling the setter of the property.

Comment: @learning: And that would be for any ORM. You can't inject property values if there's a setter method attached to a particular property. Understand that property setter can be understood as a method that gets called with one `value` parameter.